# GUI with text fields for input using Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Actually I'm a beginner, so I tried myself to create GUI using Swing where two input numbers are filled by the user in two respective fields, so there is a new text field where I want to add the 2 inputted value.

I want to add the integers of 2 text fields and add both the values and display in another text field. How to extract the `JTextField` integer values to another `JTextField`?

```
import java.io.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class GUI
{
public JFrame f;
    public JPanel p;
    public JLabel l1,l2;
    public JButton b1;
    public JButton b2;
    public JTextField t1;
    public JTextField t2;
    public JTextField t3;
    public GUI()
        {
            f=new JFrame("hello world application");
            p=new JPanel(true);
            l1=new JLabel("enter first number");
            t1=new JTextField(30);
            l2=new JLabel("\n enter the second number");
            t2=new JTextField(30);
            t3=new JTextField(30);
            b1=new JButton("check here");
            b2=new JButton("clear all");
            //b1.addActionCommand1("checking....");
            //b2.addActionCommand2("clearing all input's ....");

        }
    public void launch()
        {
            f.setSize(400,500);
            p.add(l1);
            p.add(t1);
            p.add(l2);
            p.add(t2);
            p.add(t3);
            p.add(b1);
            p.add(b2);
            f.pack();
            f.add(p);

            //l.setFont(Times Roman);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            p.setSize(400,500);
            p.setForeground(Color.red);
            p.setBackground(Color.green);
            f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            b1.addActionListener(new Button1handler(t1,t2,t3));
            b2.addActionListener(new Button2handler());
            f.setVisible(true);


        }
    public static void main(String a[])
        {
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                        {
                            GUI br=new GUI();
                            br.launch();

                        }
                });
        }
}

 class Button1handler implements ActionListener 
{

              private JTextField t1;
     private JTextField t2;
     private JTextField t3;
             public Button1handler(JTextField t1, JTextField t2, JTextField t3) 
                   {
                   this.t1 = t1;
                   this.t2 = t2;
                   this.t3 = t3;
    }
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
    System.out.println("action occurred for checking");
    String firstnumber=t1.getText();
    String secondnumber=t2.getText();
    int num1=Integer.parseInt(firstnumber);
    int num2=Integer.parseInt(secondnumber);
    int sum=num1+num2;
            String str=Integer.toString(sum);
            String sum2=t3.setText(str);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "The sum is " + sum,"Sum of Two Integers", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );



        }
}
class Button2handler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent r)
        {
            System.out.println("clearing all");

        }
}
```

In this edited code i can retrieving the sum value in message dialog box .The problem is that i can get the particular string in the 3rd JtextField.It shows error in this line:
//error: incompatible types
  String sum2=t3.setText(str);
  required: String
  found:void
1 error  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting to run the code, you have a problem here...

```
t3.setText(total);
```

Because `JTextField` does not have a `setText(int)` method.  Instead you need to convert the value to a `String`.

You can use `Integer.toString(total)`, but it might give you better results to use `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(total))` instead, for example

```
t3.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(total));
```

**Updated**

The "other" problem you have, which has had me running around in circles, is the fact that `Button1handler` extends `GUI`

```
class Button1handler extends GUI implements ActionListener {
```

This means, that when it access the fields `t1` and `t2` it's getting empty values, because these fields are not the same as the fields that are on the screen.

If your `ActionListener` is in a external file/class, you will need provide context to the class, for example...

```
class Button1handler implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField f1;
    private JTextField f2;
    private JTextField f3;

    public Button1handler(JTextField f1, JTextField f2, JTextField f3) {
        this.f1 = f1;
        this.f2 = f2;
        this.f3 = f3;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int firstnumber = Integer.parseInt(f1.getText());
        int secondnumber = Integer.parseInt(f2.getText());
        int total = firstnumber + secondnumber;
        f3.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(total));
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to create a new instance of the action handler using something like...

```
b1.addActionListener(new Button1handler(t1, t2, t3));
```

This provides the action handler with a reference to the actual fields which are been manipulated by the user on the screen...

You might be interested in [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) which provides you with some additional features to egt over this requirement (of having to pass references), but you should VERY varimular with context of objects before moving onto it ;)

Comment: can you explain me this piece of code:
t3.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(total));
though it throws an error regarding"NumberFormat"

Comment: "Throws an error" or generates a compiler error? If it's a compiler error you probably didn't import NumberFormat. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: @AndrewG It would have (eventually) thrown a `NumberFormatException` at `Integer.parseInt(f1.getText())` because the the field was empty due to a referecing issue

Comment: i've tried that too, still throws an error
error:cannot find symbol  <NumberFormat>
symbol:variable NumberFormat
location:Button1handler

Comment: Add the `import java.text.NumberFormat` to the imports section

Comment: i've edited my code .Could you just take a look , i hope you can sort it out